# How to get the observation value by using the index number in r

Tags: r, indexing

I have tried to find the answers but i could only find the other way arround (get the index number of the observation).

in the following table:

```
index  Name  Age    
1      a     10    
2      b     16    
3      c     15    
4      d     12
```

How could I get the name of the oldest person?
I have used `which.max(Age)` and i get the index number 4.
Thanks

Comment: `df$Name[which.max(Age)]` or `df[which.max(Age),"Name"]`. Please read a tutorial.

Comment: or `df[which.max(df$Age),]$Name`

Comment: Surely the maximum age has index 2, not 4?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been through the tutorials and through the questions  before I asked the question.